# Existence of a non zero element in the dual

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $S$ a vector subspace  of a normed vector space $X$ such that $\overline{S} \neq X$. Show that, **with the Hahn-Banach Theorem (Geometric Version)**, that there is $F\in X^{\prime}$ such that $\|F\|\neq 0$ and $F(x) = 0$ for all $x\in S$.

I know how to prove it, using a consequence of the Hahn-Banach Theorem with the distance function, but I don't know how do it without that result. Please help me and thanx in advance.

Comment: I'm also curious whether we can do this in ZF.

Comment: Is there a hypothesis missing, for example $X/\overline{S}$ of finite dimension? @NateEldredge: It's impossible to prove this in ZF. It is consistent that there are normed spaces that do not admit any linear functional to $\mathbb{R}$ (for example $\ell_\infty/c_0$ in Solovay's model). Consider $X = Y \oplus \mathbb{R}$ with $S = \mathbb{R} = \overline{S}$. If there were such an $F$ then it would give a non-trivial functional on $Y$.

Comment: I don't know @Martin, I wrote the problem exactly like is in my homework.

Comment: As I said, I don't think this is possible. Maybe they wanted you to consider the projection $X \to X/\overline{S}$ and compose it with a non-zero continuous linear functional on $X/\overline{S}$. But to prove the existence of such a functional you need something like Hahn-Banach.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks, I suspected that might be the case.  So we will have to use something nontrivial to substitute for Hahn-Banach.  It's hard to guess what the professor has in mind.

Comment: I'm going to ask to my professor, and then I will write here his hints. Thank you so much

Comment: My professor said that I need to use the Hahn-Banach (Geometric Version). Thanks

Comment: There is quite a big difference between "without using Hahn-Banach" and "using the geometric version of Hahn-Banach". The former is impossible while the latter is probably rather pointless since the geometric and the analytic version of Hahn-Banach are equivalent in ZF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do it in the real case first.

Take $x\in X\setminus\overline{S}$.

Applying the [geometric version of Hahn-Banach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Hahn.E2.80.93Banach_separation_theorem) to the closed convex set $\overline{S}$ disjoint from the compact convex set $\{x\}$, we obtain a continuous linear form $L:X\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and two real numbers $s,t$ such that
$$
L(x)>s>t>L(y)\qquad\forall y\in\overline{S}.
$$
Now, since $\overline{S}$ is a subspace of $X$, $L(\overline{S})$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $\mathbb{R}$ or $\{0\}$. Since the above condition implies that it is bounded above, it must be the latter case, i.e. $L$ is zero on $\overline{S}$. Therefore
$$
L(x)>0=L(y)\qquad\forall y\in\overline{S}.
$$

In the complex case, just recall that if $L=u+iv$ is a complex linear form with real part $u$ and imaginary part $v$, then
$$
v(y)=\mbox{Im}\;L(y)=\mbox{Im}\;(-iL(iy))=\mbox{Im}\;(-i(u(iy)+iv(iy))=-u(iy).
$$
So you get $u=v=0$, whence $L=0$ on $\overline{S}$ while $L(x)\neq 0$.

Comment: Who is $\overline{F}$ ?

Comment: @FASCH Typo: it is $\overline{S}$. Thanks.